# Проверка строки на пустоту jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется код формы

```
 <form action="/HomeController/WriteToFileAsync/" method="post" Name="test" id="form" >
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FName, "Введите Фамилию")
        <br> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FName, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "FName", onblur = "validName(this)" } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FName)
        <br>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Введите Имя" )
        <br>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Name", onblur = "validName(this)" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        <br>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LName, "Введите Отчество")
        <br>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LName,  htmlAttributes: new { @id = "LName" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LName)
        <br>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Opisanie, "Введите Описание")
        <br>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Opisanie, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Opisanie" })
        <br>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date, "Введите Дату рождения")
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="Date" placeholder="Дата рождения" id="Date" onchange="validate_date(this);" />
        <div id="error"></div><br />    
        <input type="button" id="submitIt" value="Отправить заявку" />
    </form>
```

Хочу проверить строки FName на пустоту, написал подобный код:

```
$('#FName').on('keyup', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val();
        if (val.length >= 1) {
            $('#submitIt').show(100);
        } else {
            $('#submitIt').hide(100);
        }
    });
```

Но, увы, не выходит, конечно же можно условием все проверить, но хотелось бы с jquery управится,

Comment: Вы ведь и так условием проверяете же. У вас `FName` это разве инпут?

Comment: Я в том смысле, что без jquery чисто условием, нет, не input, это хелпер с id FName

Comment: с чего вы взяли тогда, что у него есть св-во `val`? Какой это тег?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text">


let inpt = document.querySelector('input');

inpt.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
})
```

Можно делать любые проверки, вроде и на чистом js кода немного )